# (Magento) How to set freeshipping in shopping cart when none is selected?

Tags: events, magento, shopping-cart

I tried using the event "controller_predispatch_checkout_cart_index" and used this function. Only to mention after i login, and go direct to page/checkout/cart, it does not work, but after reloading the page it does work... Whats happening???

```php
    const FREE_CODE = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';

    public function predispatchCart($observer)
    {
        $quote      = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();



        if(! $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod())
        {
            $quote->getShippingAddress()
                    ->setShippingMethod(self::FREE_CODE);
                    //->save();
            return true;
        }
   }
}
```